# To split for-cycle using TPL

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

In order to parallelize and accelerate calculations I"ve splitted one long for-cycle by two short for-cycles using TPL, these parts are called PointGenerator and PointGenerator2 in my class bellow:

```
class CalcPiTPL
    {
        int n;
        int totalCounter;
        int counter1;
        int counter2;
        double aPi;
        public StringBuilder Msg; // diagonstic message
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

        public void Init(int aN)
        {
            stopWatch.Start();
            n = aN; // save total calculate-iterations amount
            aPi = -1; // flag, if no any calculate-iteration has been completed
            Msg = new StringBuilder("No any calculate-iteration has been completed");
        }
        public void Run()
        {
            if (n < 1)
            {
                Msg = new StringBuilder("Invalid N-value");
                return;
            }

            Task[] tasks = new Task[2];
            tasks[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew((obj) => { PointGenerator((int)obj); }, n);
            tasks[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew((obj) => { PointGenerator2((int)obj); }, n);

            Task.WaitAll(tasks[0], tasks[1]);
            totalCounter = counter1 + counter2;
            aPi = 4.0 * ((double)totalCounter / (double)n); // to calculate approximate Pi - value
            Console.WriteLine(aPi);
            stopWatch.Stop();
            TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
            string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
            Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
        }
        public double Done()
        {
            if (aPi > 0)
            {
                Msg = new StringBuilder("Calculates has been completed successful");
                return aPi; // return gotten value
            }
            else
            {
                return 0; // no result
            }
        }
        public void PointGenerator(int n)//FIRST PART OF ONE BIG FOR-CYCLE
        {
            double s = 0.125;
            double sP = s / (n / 2);
            double x = Math.Sqrt(sP);
            for (double cX = 0; cX <= 0.25; cX += x)
            {
                for (double cY = 0; cY <= 0.5; cY += x)
                {
                    if (((cX - 0.5) * (cX - 0.5) + (cY - 0.5) * (cY - 0.5)) < 0.25)
                    {
                        counter1++; // coordinate in a circle! mark it by incrementing N_0
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void PointGenerator2(int n)//SECOND PART OF ONE BIG FOR-CYCLE
        {
            double s = 0.125;
            double sP = s / (n / 2);
            double x = Math.Sqrt(sP);
            for (double cX = 0.25; cX <= 0.5; cX += x)
            {
                for (double cY = 0; cY <= 0.5; cY += x)
                {
                    if (((cX - 0.5) * (cX - 0.5) + (cY - 0.5) * (cY - 0.5)) < 0.25)
                    {
                        counter2++; // coordinate in a circle! mark it by incrementing N_0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the same class without Tasks using(TPL), it has one long for-cycle:

```
class TCalcPi//unparallel calculating method
    {
        int N;
        int n_0;
        double aPi;
        public StringBuilder Msg; // diagnostic message


        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

        public void Init(int aN)
        {
            stopWatch.Start();
            N = aN; // save total calculate-iterations amount
            aPi = -1; // flag, if no any calculate-iteration has been completed
            Msg = new StringBuilder("No any calculate-iteration has been completed");
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            if (N < 1)
            {
                Msg = new StringBuilder("Invalid N - value");
                return;
            }

            double s = 0.25;
            double sP = s / N;
            double x = Math.Sqrt(sP);
            for (double cX = 0; cX <= 0.5; cX += x)//ONE LONG FOR-CYCLE
            {
                for(double cY = 0; cY <= 0.5; cY += x)
                {
                    if (((cX - 0.5) * (cX - 0.5) + (cY - 0.5) * (cY - 0.5)) < 0.25)
                    {
                        n_0++; // coordinate in a circle! mark it by incrementing N_0
                    }
                }
            }
            aPi = 4.0 * ((double)n_0 / (double)N); // to calculate approximate Pi - value
            stopWatch.Stop();
            TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
            string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
            Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
        }
        public double Done()
        {
            if (aPi > 0)
            {
                Msg = new StringBuilder("Calculates has been completed successful");
                return aPi; // return gotten value
            }
            else
            {
                return 0; // no result
            }
        }
    }
```

But unparallelized-class works faster, than parallelized(using TPL)class. How to fix it?

Comment: Try Parallel.For as well. The logic in the Parallel.For that decides how many Tasks should be created takes into consideration the amount of cores. It might give you better/interesting results.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd, Thanks, but I need to use TPL-library exactly.

Comment: @pragmus Setting aside the fact that `Parallel.For` is a part of TPL, why do you *need* to use TPL directly?

Comment: @pragmus `Task.Factory.StartNew` is not part of TPL. All TPL methods are under the classes `System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel`, `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow` and `System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable`. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information on what is (and is not) TPL.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek, this is an one of my tasks: to compare different parallelization methods such as TPL, PLINQ and Parrallel.For

Comment: @pragmus You can't compare TPL and PLINQ or Parallel.For because PLINQ and Parallel.For are two ways of doing parallel actions in the TPL library. Are you sure you are not supposed to compare "DataFlow", "Parallel.For", and "PLINQ"? Those being the 3 ways to do parallel actions in TPL that would make more sense as a task to perform. It is like you are saying "I need to compare `System.Collections.Generic`, `List<T>`, and `HashSet<T>`", you can't compare the first to the second two because the second two are just parts of the first item.

Comment: @pragmus - what a strange requirement. Could you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`counter1` and `counter2` most likely sit on the same cache line because they are adjacent in memory. This causes [False Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing). Probably, you are incrementing those counters very often. This pings the cacheline between the L1's of two cores for every alternation in time between the counters.

Separate them. As a proof of concept, like this:

```
int counter1;
long padding0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7; //64 bytes padding
int counter2;
```

Let's hope the JIT does not reorder the fields. Maybe you need to use `StructLayout`.

Alternatively, make the counters local variables. Stack variables only have false sharing by extreme coincidence.